# Is every even number a value of the Carmichael function?

Tags: number-theory

Except for the 1, all other values of the [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda$ are even. Does $\lambda$ take all even numbers? Is there an infinite family of even numbers that are not values of $\lambda$ ?

This question arose in the comments to [What is the inverse of the Carmichael-function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41061/what-is-the-inverse-of-the-carmichael-function).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Carmichael function is defined recursively by the following formulas:

1. If $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ are distinct primes, then
   $$
   \lambda(p_1^{k_1} \cdots p_n^{k_n}) \;=\; \text{lcm}\bigl(\lambda(p_1^{k_1}),\ldots,\lambda(p_n^{k_n})\bigr)
   $$
2. If $p$ is an odd prime and $k\geq 1$, then $\lambda(p^k) = p^{k-1}(p-1)$.
3. $\lambda(2) = 1$, $\lambda(4) = 2$, and $\lambda(2^k) = 2^{k-2}$ for $k \geq 3$.

Since $\lambda(p^k)$ is even for any prime power $p^k$ other than $2$, the values Carmichael function are always even except for $\lambda(1) = \lambda(2) = 1$.

Moreover, if $p$ is an odd prime and $p \mid \lambda(n)$, then either:

1. $(p-1) \mid \lambda(n)$, or
2. $p \mid (q-1)$ and $(q-1) \mid \lambda(n)$ for some prime $q$.

This places severe restrictions on the values of the Carmichael function.  In particular, if $p$ is an odd prime and $2p+1$ is not prime, then $2p$ is not a possible value of the Carmichael function.  Thus, the numbers $\{14,26,34,38,\ldots\}$ do not arise as values of the Carmichael function.

Note that this list is not exhaustive.  For example, $68$ is not a value of the Carmichael function, though it is not of the form I have indicated.

Comment: $14,26,34,38$ are also not values of Euler's $\phi$: http://oeis.org/A005277 . Is there a number that is taken by $\phi$ but not by $\lambda$? And conversely? (Perhaps this should be a separate question...)

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A002174 for the list of values taken by $\lambda$.  Apparently 90 is a value for $\lambda$ but not for $\phi$,

Answer (score 2):

Also note that the list of even value not taken by $\lambda$ or $\phi$ is infinite. In fact, it can be shown that most even numbers are not in the image of either $\lambda$ or $\phi$.

Comment: For example, if m=2p, where p is a prime, yet 2p+1 is not a prime, then there is no solution to either \lambda(n)=m or \phi(n)=m.